# "on the part of " : What does it mean in the sentence?

Tags: sentence-construction, idioms

When I say,

*He expressed appreciation **on the part of** himself and his colleagues*,

Does it mean he expressed appreciation on behalf of  himself and his colleagues?

or

Does it mean he appreciated himself and his colleagues?.

Answer (score 1):

The former. "On the part of" in this context is equivalent to "on behalf of". As a matter of usage, I would avoid this construction, as I find it to be awkward, clunky and verbose.

Comment: **On my part**, you can do whatever you please to do.  What does the person is trying to say here?  I understand that the person is simply telling about his opinion as to what the other person is supposed to do. Am I correct?